# Разрешение на сохранение файла Python

Tags: python, изображения, permissions, pil, pillow

Этот код

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save(r'D:/MyFilesForProject/Network/screen.jpg')
```

вызывает эту ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/PycharmProjects/2.7NetworkExersice/Screenshot.py", line 4, in 
<module>
im.save(r'D:\MyFilesForProject\Network\screen.jpg')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1676, in save
fp = builtins.open(fp, "wb")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'D:\\MyFilesForProject\\Network\\screen.jpg'
```

Я пытался найти решение во всём чёртовом интернете и ничего работающего я не нашёл. В о избежание повторяющихся советов: да, я разрешал чтение и запись папки в свойствах и пробовал сохранить в другом месте. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: То есть при сохранении в любое место именно из Python возникает эта ошибка, но любым другим способом файл в тех же каталогах вы создать можете?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не подскажите ли другие методы сохранения файла? Я новичок, поэтому не осведомлён с иными способами сохранения

Comment: Открываете каталог в проводнике, например, кликате правой клавишей мыши, выбираете в контекстном мнню пункт "Создать файл"

Comment: пробовали любой другой путь указать? Вы как-то сумели Screenshot.py создать. Попробуйте в ту же директорию где py файл лежит сохранить jpg для проверки. Для проверки можно `open("test.txt", "wb").close()` использовать (если это работает, то im.save("test.jpg") тоже должен работать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я думал вы о других методах создания файлов на питоне. А так как вы сказали я уже пробовал - создаёт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустите ваш код из под администратора (запустите cmd под администратором, и в нем вашу программу).

Если запустится - значит вы неправильно выставили разрешения у папки.

Comment: "C:\WINDOWS\system32>D:\PycharmProjects\2.7NetworkExersice\Screenshot.pyc
Устройство не готово." Такая вот ошибка вылезает. Разрешения для папки выставлены правильно, могу скрин прислать.

Comment: @AlexShvachko Вышлите пожалуйста скриншоты разрешений для папки. Еще попробуйте запустить программу не из Pycharm, а напрямую из командной строки.